# Creating strings for lcd-data

Tags: vhdl

I want to create dynamic string array, so I can transmit it to the lcd module on my Altera DE2-115 board. So far the most part is working, but the last part is not wrking in the following code:

```
CREATE_STRING:  PROCESS (CLK, RESET, X)
    BEGIN
        IF RESET = '1' THEN
            FOR i IN 0 TO 31 LOOP
                lcd_data(i) <= x"30";
            END LOOP;
        END IF;

        IF X /= 0 THEN
            FOR i IN 0 TO 15 LOOP
                IF X(15-i) = '0' THEN   
                    lcd_data(i) <= x"30";
                END IF;
                IF X(15-i) ='1' THEN 
                    lcd_data(i) <= x"31";
                END IF;
            END LOOP;
        END IF;

        IF char_count > 15 AND lcd_y = '1' THEN 
            ELSIF CLK = '1' AND CLK'event THEN
                lcd_data(to_integer(char_count)) <= x"31";
        END IF;

END PROCESS CREATE_STRING;
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
Error (10818): Can't infer register for "lcd_data[31][0]" at seqdec.vhd(75) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge
```

for every lcd_data[31][x].

I googled the error and if I am not completly on the wrong thought I think i understood it, but I'm still not able the get it right...

Would be great if somebody could help with advice.

Best regards 
Adrian

Did this change:

```
CREATE_STRING:  PROCESS (CLK, RESET)
    BEGIN
        IF RESET = '1' THEN
            FOR i IN 0 TO 31 LOOP
                lcd_data(i) <= x"30";
            END LOOP;

        ELSIF CLK = '1' AND CLK'event THEN
            IF X /= 0 THEN
                FOR i IN 0 TO 15 LOOP
                    IF X(15-i) = '0' THEN   
                        lcd_data(i) <= x"30";
                    END IF;
                    IF X(15-i) ='1' THEN 
                        lcd_data(i) <= x"31";
                    END IF;
                END LOOP;
            END IF;
        ELSIF lcd_y = '1' THEN  
                lcd_data(to_integer(pos_count)) <= x"31";
        END IF;

END PROCESS CREATE_STRING;
```

But still the same problem.

Comment: You are doing too much outside the clocked part of the process. Juergen's answer looks good...

Comment: As Juergen suggested you have to put also the assignment when `lcd_y='1'` into the `ELSIF CLK = '1' AND CLK'event THEN` block.

Answer (score 2):

To properly describe a register, you must reverse the order of the if statements as follows:

```
CREATE_STRING:  PROCESS (CLK, RESET)
    BEGIN
        IF RESET = '1' THEN
            FOR i IN 0 TO 31 LOOP
                lcd_data(i) <= x"30";
            END LOOP;
        ELSIF CLK = '1' AND CLK'event THEN
            IF X /= 0 THEN
                FOR i IN 0 TO 15 LOOP
                    IF X(15-i) = '0' THEN   
                        lcd_data(i) <= x"30";
                    END IF;
                    IF X(15-i) ='1' THEN 
                        lcd_data(i) <= x"31";
                    END IF;
                END LOOP;
            END IF;

            IF char_count > 15 AND lcd_y = '1' THEN 
                lcd_data(to_integer(char_count)) <= x"31";
            END IF;
        END IF;
END PROCESS CREATE_STRING;
```

Comment: when I write it that way I get the error:Error (10821): HDL error at seqdec.vhd(76): can't infer register for "lcd_data[15][0]" because its behavior does not match any supported register model
And I have to admit that the part with X should not be triggered with CLK, but only with X

Comment: Make sure your target FPGA technology supports asynchronous reset. If you can, you should use synchronous resets only (my personal opinion). Same thing applies to your X signal: make it work synchronously (or explain in detail why you think it is necessary to be asynchronous).

Comment: I admit it can be synchronous, but I think it is too much for one process, i read a post that this could cause him to think of two different clocks, but this is not possible.
But now I don't know how to handle this in a different way in one process.
I want him to build String with 16 positions for top line and 16 for bottom line, but with different requirements.

Comment: @DaPole You have made an edit to your question just after Juergen has posted his answer. It looks nearly the same, but is different at the last `ELSIF`. You have to put also the assignment when `lcd_y='1'` into the `ELSIF CLK = '1' AND CLK'event THEN` block. And **not after it**.

Comment: I suggest to give also a code pattern for a clock-edge triggered register with an asynchronous reset.